# Ошибка в запросе mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM cart,table_products WHERE cart.cart_ip = '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}' AND table_products.products_id = cart.cart_id_product");
```

выдает ошибку:

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

Comment: Советую прочитать внимательно ошибку. Если непонятно - обратиться в гугл переводчик..... далее внимательно прочитать документацию по php `mysqli_query`. и сделать соответствующий вывод на основе полученных знаний .... возможно что-то из этого поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli_result%2C+boolean+given+in

Answer (score -1):

Из [php-документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php):

`mysqli::query` возвращает **FALSE** в случае неудачи. В случае успешного выполнения запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN mysqli_query() вернет объект **mysqli_result**. Для остальных успешных запросов mysqli_query() вернет TRUE.